# Minted: Using command for used language with inputminted

Tags: packages, minted, parameters

I have multiple different commands setup using \inputminted with different options but all are using the same language. Previously, i could feed all commands with a TeX primitive like so:

```
\def \usedlanguage{c}
\newcommand{\macro1}[1]{\inputminted[\breaklines,\fontsize\footnotesize]{\usedlanguage}{#1}
\newcommand{\macro2}[1]{\inputminted[\breaklines]{\usedlanguage}{#1}
```

etc.

Since i updated my packages recently this leaves me with the error

> Error: no lexer for alias '\usedlanguage ' found

Has anyone encountered this or a similar problem and has come up with a solution?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't test it here but maybe `\newmintedfile[macrofirst]{\usedlanguage}{breaklines,fontsize=\footnotesize}` and then `\macrofirst{yourfile.c}` would work.

Comment: Hi,
I have the same issue, I opened an issue at https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/353

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PolDellaiera thanks for digging into this! As pointed out by some nice guy named muzimuzhi in your [issue](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/353), this is seems to be a bug introduced with minted v2.7. In this [issue](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/354) a workaround is proposed which seems to have worked for you, so it might work for others as well.

Since my goal was only to have a single source of truth for the language in use, i started to use \newmintedfile to define my personal macros:

```
\newmintedfile[codefile]{c}{breaklines}
\newcommand{\macro1}[2][firstline=1]{\codefile[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\macro2}[2][fontsize=\footnotesize]{\codefile[#1]{#2}}
```

This way, i only have to update the definition of codefile when using a different language.