# Unable to use variables with `\inputminted`

Tags: minted

I'm working on refactoring the building of the open-source book at https://github.com/hmemcpy/milewski-ctfp-pdf. Basically, it was using very old dependencies and I'm refreshing everything.

After upgrading the LaTeX version and python version, I notice that I'm unable to build the document. I'm now stuck because `\inputminted` is not working as I would expect. Obviously, I might be wrong, but it seems that it doesn't use the value of a variable, but the variable itself. I spent the whole day yesterday trying to figure out what I was doing wrong, without luck.

I tried to reproduce a minimal working environment, here it is:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[cache=false,kpsewhich]{minted}

\def\OPTCustomLanguage{ocaml}
\def\OPTCustomLanguageExt{ml}

\NewDocumentCommand{\src}{m}{
  \srcsnippet{code/haskell/#1.hs}{haskell}
  \srcsnippet{code/\OPTCustomLanguage/#1.\OPTCustomLanguageExt}{\OPTCustomLanguage}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\srcsnippet}{mm}{
  \inputminted{#2}{#1}
}
\begin{document}

\src{snippet01}

\end{document}
```

Create the `src` files:

```shell
touch code/haskell/snippet01.hs
touch code/ocaml/snippet01.ml
```

Then compile the document... and the error is:

```
(/nix/store/nr191iv6nas2ayhwg86v6rdnrymn5lmn-texlive-combined-2022/share/texmf/
tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def) (build/ctfp-ocaml.aux)
(/nix/store/nr191iv6nas2ayhwg86v6rdnrymn5lmn-texlive-combined-2022/share/texmf/
tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) (./ctfp-ocaml.out.pyg) (./ctfp-ocaml.out.pyg)Error: no lexer for alias '\\OPTCustomLanguage ' found
system returned with code 256
```

Can you tell me if I'm doing something wrong here?

PS: after a bit of search on [stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com), I found these related issues:

- [Minted: Using command for used language with inputminted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671117/minted-using-command-for-used-language-with-inputminted)

Comment: The solution is to add a `\ExpandArgs{ee}` in `srcsnippet`.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the author of `minted` package (see more on the Github issue at https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/353):

> An expansion issue. Fully expanding args of \inputminted before it absorbs them does the trick.

The fixed code:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[cache=false,kpsewhich]{minted}

\def\OPTCustomLanguage{ocaml}
\def\OPTCustomLanguageExt{ml}

\NewDocumentCommand{\src}{m}{%
  \srcsnippet{code/haskell/#1.hs}{haskell}%
  \srcsnippet{code/\OPTCustomLanguage/#1.\OPTCustomLanguageExt}{\OPTCustomLanguage}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\srcsnippet}{mm}{%
  \ExpandArgs{ee}%
  \inputminted{#2}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\src{snippet01}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You had several unprotected endlines. You'll get unwanted spaces.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Did you notice where I put those `%` characters? Any such place would add a space in the token stream (which *might* be ignored, but also might not).

Comment: Ok, understood. Thanks !

Comment: A reference for the `%`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/107497

Comment: Thanks once again :)